# Where or how I install directories with different file formats with setup.py?

Tags: python, flask, pip, setup.py

I'm developing a module with python, now I understand how to install module with `setup.py` or `setuptools` and how to build a command line utility/tool for the user. I do not understand where & how I install some directories with different files, for example the module has a web interface, this interface of course have html, js, css, etc files.

How should I configure the `setup.py` to install this files in some path?

Cheers!

Comment: Please consider adding a code sample related to this question. As it currently stands, it makes it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that.

Comment: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/packages/

Comment: @SudheeshSinganamalla yep you're right, I'll add an example of my project and how to I configured the setup.py, thanks for the edition :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`package_data` is probably what you want. See https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-package-data